# Null Pointer exception when trying to access the parent layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have a relative layout with three buttons in it and I am trying to change the background of the relative layout dynamically. Here's the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/mbi2"
            android:id="@+id/rlMain"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
    <Button android:text="Compose" 
            android:id="@+id/btnCompose" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
    <Button android:text="Messages" 
            android:id="@+id/btnMessages" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btnCompose"/>
    <Button android:text="More &gt;&gt;" 
            android:id="@+id/btnMore" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btnMessages"/>                    
            </RelativeLayout>
```

Here's the java code which is giving me an error

```
            RelativeLayout llMain=null;
    try {
        llMain = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlMain);
        Resources res = getResources();
        Drawable drawMbi = res.getDrawable(drawBgId);
        llMain.setBackgroundDrawable(drawMbi);          
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The error is

```
06-29 23:56:41.099: WARN/System.err(8487): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-29 23:56:41.099: WARN/System.err(8487):     at com.me2youmob.cwrap.ChickenWrapActivity.loadMBIIntoView(ChickenWrapActivity.java:65)
06-29 23:56:41.099: WARN/System.err(8487):     at com.me2youmob.cwrap.ChickenWrapActivity.onCreate(ChickenWrapActivity.java:23)
06-29 23:56:41.099: WARN/System.err(8487):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1066)
06-29 23:56:41.099: WARN/System.err(8487):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2797)
06-29 23:56:41.108: WARN/System.err(8487):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2854)
06-29 23:56:41.108: WARN/System.err(8487):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:136)
06-29 23:56:41.118: WARN/System.err(8487):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2179)
06-29 23:56:41.118: WARN/System.err(8487):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-29 23:56:41.118: WARN/System.err(8487):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
06-29 23:56:41.118: WARN/System.err(8487):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5068)
06-29 23:56:41.118: WARN/System.err(8487):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-29 23:56:41.118: WARN/System.err(8487):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-29 23:56:41.118: WARN/System.err(8487):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
06-29 23:56:41.118: WARN/System.err(8487):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
06-29 23:56:41.118: WARN/System.err(8487):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Another thing in this issue is that earlier I had the buttons within a linear layout which was then within a Relative Layout. I thought it was not able to reach the relative layout and remove the linear layout section. It still gives me the same error.

Any idea what is going on here ?

NEW UPDATE:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    RelativeLayout rlM = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlMain);
    if (rlM == null)
    {
        Log.d("NULL CHECK","Layout is null");
    }
    else
    {
        Log.d("NULL CHECK","Layout is not null");
    }
    //spPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    //loadMBIIntoView();
    //handleButtonClicks();
}
```

Comment: which is line 65? which line throws error?

Comment: llMain = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlMain); This is line. The llMain is always null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `View.findViewById()` function will only find views that are children of the current view you are in.

In this case, you're trying to obtain the main view either within one of the children views, or you have not used `setContentView()` within the Activity class yet.

If you are trying to set your background, I would highly suggest doing so from the Activity.

Comment: I added new code update. I am getting Layout is null and yes it is within the activity.

Answer (score 0):

I  try your code just now ,no problem,I think you haven' t invokered the  setContentView().
ps:get the pointer of the main view is OK.

Comment: I have invoked the setContentView. For some reason I am not getting an instance of the RelativeLayout which is main parent in the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use LayoutInflater like this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
RelativeLayout rlMain = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.rlMain, null);

//do stuff with rlMain

setContentView(rlMain);
```